# Subscription to kinesis data stream gets disconnected while reading data from it

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I'm currently reading data from kinesis data streams using enhanced fan-out consumer. I have a working code but it unsubscribes from the shard after sometime of connection.

Here is my code for the same:-

```
const {
  KinesisClient,
  SubscribeToShardCommand,
} = require("@aws-sdk/client-kinesis");

const kinesis = new KinesisClient({ region: "ap-south-1" });

const streamName = "data-stream-1";
const shardId = "shardId";

const readFromShard = async () => {
  const command = new SubscribeToShardCommand({
    StreamName: streamName,
    ConsumerARN: `arn:aws:kinesis:region:id:stream/stream-name/consumer/consumer-name:1283264891`,
    ShardId: shardId,
    StartingPosition: {
      Type: "LATEST",
    },
  });

  try {
    const response = await kinesis.send(command);
    // Handle the received records
    for await (const record of response.EventStream) {
      if (record.SubscribeToShardEvent.Records) {
        if (record.SubscribeToShardEvent.Records.length > 0) {
          for (const recordData of record.SubscribeToShardEvent.Records) {
            const payload = Buffer.from(recordData.Data).toString("utf-8");
            console.log(payload);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    console.log("Subscription closed: ");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
};

readFromShard();
```

After sometime after reading 7-9 records the code directly executes this line

```
console.log("Subscription closed: ");
```

And thereafter ends the execution of the code.
How do I keep the connection alive for the same? Or maybe read records and then stop for a while for 5-6 seconds and then again read it from stream, if it is feasible to do it.

Any help to solve to problem will be greatly appreciated.